# How to get range of data types in c#?

Tags: c#

How to get range of data types in c sharp .net ? For example if I wish to get range of uint datatype, how can I get it through code ?

Comment: what do you mean by range? min / max values for numeric types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see this sample reference -->

- **UInt64.MinValue Field** - Represents the smallest possible value of UInt64. This field is constant. MSDN Link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.minvalue.aspx
- **UInt64.MaxValue Field** - Represents the largest possible value of UInt64. This field is constant.
  MSDN Link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.maxvalue.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No standard, sorry.

But they all implement IIRC MinValue and MaxValue, so you could use reflect to get those static items.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use:

```
uint.MinValue
```

and

```
uint.MaxValue
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean min/max values for numeric types they are usually defined as constants on that type. Eg.: int.MaxValue;